# Access Violation from R2R (ready-to-run) assembly when using GetTypes() from a thread in Net Core (Net7)

Tags: c#, .net-core, access-violation, assembly-loading

I am in a thread where I am using

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Assemblies
```

to retrieve the loaded assemblies and call `GetTypes()` on them.

In the list of assemblies there is also `PresentationFramework` which turns to be a ready-to-run (R2R) assembly. When calling `GetTypes()` or even inspecting the assembly instance in the Watch or Immediate Window, I get an access violation.

Is it there a way to properly deal with R2R assemblies and make sure I can get the types or skip the file altogether?